# Reading from beginning (offset = 0) of topic with Spring Kafka / Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

How can I start reading the topic from the beginning every time my application starts, if I have a @KafkaListener annotation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use an anonymous group management: no `id()` and no `groupId()` for that `@KafkaListener`. If `idIsGroup() == true` (default), of course.

And you also need use a `@TopicPartition` like explained here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.2/reference/html/#manual-assignment

> Starting with version 2.5.5, you can apply an initial offset to all assigned partitions:

```
topicPartitions = { @TopicPartition(topic = "topic1", 
         partitionOffsets = @PartitionOffset(partition = "*", initialOffset = "0"))
    })
```

Another way is to implement an `AbstractConsumerSeekAware` for your `@KafkaListener` class and call that `ConsumerSeekCallback.seekToBeginning()` when you get partitions assigned in the `onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback)`.